# Build Error python library, version issue: cannot find my_package.version

Tags: python-3.x, build, pip, version

I have setup.cfg, I am able to build when I specify specific version inside setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
version = 0.0.1
```

But when I specify inside version as variable inside setup.cfg: I am getting build error: unable to find my_package

```
version = attr: my_package.VERSION
```

**Error messages:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/build-env-_y8qqaje/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 419, in _parse_attr
    return getattr(StaticModule(module_name), attr_name)
  File "/tmp/build-env-_y8qqaje/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 27, in __init__
    with open(spec.origin) as strm:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
....    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

Above is my project structure:
[image]

Any help would be helpful, this is my first time building a package